# Merge Sort: merge function array index zero returning multiple indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, merge, mergesort

I wanted to implement merge sort with Javascript as a learning experience. I have the function mergeSort(unsortedArray) which takes an unsorted array and sorts it using the merge sort strategy. mergeSort() calls merge(leftArray,rightArray), which merges two sorted arrays together to result in one sorted array.

I believe the problem is with the merge() function. When calling mergeSort on the array:[8,8,7,5,4,6,3,2,1,5,9,8,7,6,5,4,2,3,6,5,4,8] I'm getting the result:[1,4,2,3,5,5,9,6,7,8,8]. The root of the problem as far as I know is that in the merge() function, when doing the comparison of leftArray[0] and rightArray[0], the rightArray[0] is sometimes returning multiple values instead of just the first index. In my case its doing it with 2,3 and 5,9. So when the code runs, rightArray[0] = 2,3 sometimes, and rightArray[0]=5,9 after the 2,3 is spliced off the array. Here's what happens within merge() when this problem occurs:

### Step1

leftArray:[4,5,6,7,8,8]
rightArray:[1,2,3,5,9]
result: []

### Step2

leftArray[4,5,6,7,8,8]
rightArray[2,3,5,9]
result:[1]

### Step3

(improper indexing... array[0] is returning two values)
leftArray[0]=4 
rightArray[0]=2,3

leftArray[5,6,7,8,8] 
rightArray[2,3,5,9] 
result[1,4]

### Step4

(improper indexing... array[0] is returning two values)
leftArray[0]=5
rightArray[0]=2,3

leftArray[5,6,7,8,8]
rightArray[5,9]
result[1,4,2,3]

...The array[0] index screws up again and returns rightArray[0] = 5,9 next. The weird part is if I call my merge() function on leftArray=[4,5,6,7,8,8] and rightArray[1,2,3,5,9] independant of mergeSort() it works fine and returns the proper result without the weird index behavior.

```js
//Implement Merge Sort...
    function mergeSort(unsortedArray) {
        var leftArray = [];
        var rightArray = [];
        var result = [];
        
        //Base Case of one element
        if(unsortedArray.length <= 1){
            //alert("Array is size 1 and value: " + unsortedArray);
            return unsortedArray;
        }
        else{
            var halfwayPoint = Math.round(unsortedArray.length/2);
            
            //Sepertate unsortedArray into a left and right array
            for(var i = 0; i < halfwayPoint; i++){
                leftArray.push(unsortedArray[i]);
                //alert("leftArray: "+ leftArray + " index i = " + i);
            }
            for(var i = halfwayPoint; i < unsortedArray.length; i++){
                rightArray.push(unsortedArray[i]);
                //alert("rightArray" + rightArray + " index i = " + i);
            }
            //alert("leftArray: " + leftArray + " rightArray: " + rightArray);
            leftArray = mergeSort(leftArray);
            rightArray = mergeSort(rightArray);
            //alert("Arrays before merge = leftArray: " + leftArray + " rightArray: " + rightArray);
            result = merge(leftArray, rightArray);
            //alert("result: " + result);
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    //Helper function Merge for MergeSort
    function merge(leftArray, rightArray)
    {
        var result = [];
        while(leftArray.length > 0 && rightArray.length > 0){
            //compare first items of both lists
            //alert("top of while loop");
            //alert("leftArray[0] = " + leftArray[0] + " rightArray[0] = " + rightArray[0]);
            if(leftArray[0] >= rightArray[0]){
                result.push(rightArray[0]);
                //alert("result after push rightArray[0] " + result + " and rightArray before splice: "+ rightArray);
                rightArray.splice(0,1);
                //alert("rightArray after splce: " + rightArray);
            }
            else{
                result.push(leftArray[0]);
                //alert("result after push leftArray[0] " + result + " and leftArray before splice: "+ leftArray);
                leftArray.splice(0,1);
                //alert("leftArray after splce: " + leftArray);
            }
        }
        //alert("before leftArray add");
        if(leftArray.length > 0){
            //alert("went into left array > 0 leftArray: " + leftArray);
            result.push(leftArray);
        }
        //alert("before rightArray add");
        if(rightArray.length > 0){
            //alert("went into right array > 0 rightArray: " + rightArray);
            result.push(rightArray);
        }
        //alert("result within merge function: " + result);
        return result;
    }
    //Test Case
    var unsortedArray = [8,8,7,5,4,6,3,2,1,5,9,8,7,6,5,4,2,3,6,5,4,8];
    var sortedArray = mergeSort(unsortedArray);
    lert(sortedArray);
  
    //Problem is when Merge sort has left array and right array described below
    //the merge function will yield proper result on left array and right array
    //if called directly as it is below, however when merge is called through
    //mergeSort with leftArray and rightArray as described below it yields
    // improperResult below
    var leftArray = [4,5,6,7,8,8];
    var rightArray = [1,2,3,5,9];
    var improperResult= [1,4,2,3,5,5,9,6,7,8,8];
    var resultAct = merge(leftArray,rightArray);
    alert(resultAct);
```

```html
<h1>MergeSort Problem</h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead of `.push()` to concat 2 `arrays.`

`.concat` combines 2 (or more) arrays and return a new `array`, while push just put the target to the end of the `array`, it doesn't concat arrays for you.

If you log your original result instead of alert, you'll see

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, Array[2], 5, Array[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), Array[2], Array[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), Array[2],
>   Array[4]]

Which is clear that you just pushed arrays to the result.

So in your

```
if(leftArray.length > 0){
    result.push(leftArray);
}
if(rightArray.length > 0){
    result.push(rightArray);
}
```

You should write to :

```
if(leftArray.length > 0){
    result = result.concat(leftArray);
}
if(rightArray.length > 0){
  result = result.concat(rightArray);
}
```

```js
    function mergeSort(unsortedArray) {
        var leftArray = [];
        var rightArray = [];
        var result = [];
        
        //Base Case of one element
        if(unsortedArray.length <= 1){
            return unsortedArray;
        }
        else{
            var halfwayPoint = Math.round(unsortedArray.length/2);
            
            //Sepertate unsortedArray into a left and right array
            for(var i = 0; i < halfwayPoint; i++){
                leftArray.push(unsortedArray[i]);
            }
            for(var i = halfwayPoint; i < unsortedArray.length; i++){
                rightArray.push(unsortedArray[i]);
            }

            leftArray = mergeSort(leftArray);
            rightArray = mergeSort(rightArray);
          
            result = merge(leftArray, rightArray);
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    //Helper function Merge for MergeSort
    function merge(leftArray, rightArray)
    {
        var result = [];
      
        while(leftArray.length > 0 && rightArray.length > 0){
            //compare first items of both lists
            if(leftArray[0] >= rightArray[0]){
                result.push(rightArray[0]);
                rightArray.splice(0,1);
            }
            else{
                result.push(leftArray[0]);
                leftArray.splice(0,1);
            }
        }
      
        if(leftArray.length > 0){
            result = result.concat(leftArray);
        }
        if(rightArray.length > 0){
          result = result.concat(rightArray);
        }

        return result;
    }
    //Test Case
    var unsortedArray = [8,8,7,5,4,6,3,2,1,5,9,8,7,6,5,4,2,3,6,5,4,8];
    var sortedArray = mergeSort(unsortedArray);
    alert(sortedArray);
  
    //Problem is when Merge sort has left array and right array described below
    //the merge function will yield proper result on left array and right array
    //if called directly as it is below, however when merge is called through
    //mergeSort with leftArray and rightArray as described below it yields
    // improperResult below
    var leftArray = [4,5,6,7,8,8];
    var rightArray = [1,2,3,5,9];
    var improperResult= [1,4,2,3,5,5,9,6,7,8,8];
    var resultAct = merge(leftArray,rightArray);
    alert(resultAct);
```

```html
<h1>MergeSort Problem</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks @fuyushimoya! Such an easy fix. I guess lesson learned here is that I didn't understand exactly how push worked or that concat was the proper function to use. Thanks again!